# How can I solve "cannot import name 'plot_2d_separator' from 'figures' " error?

Tags: python, figure

I was trying to draw a linear decision function which separates the two regions of data points in 2d input space using `plot_2d_seperator` function from `figures` module, even though `figures` and other modules have been installed in my device. But it is showing an error attached below.

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_blobs
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from figures import plot_2d_separator
```

It throws the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-69-4a72dfe173de> in <module>
      2 from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
      3 from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
----> 4 from figures import plot_2d_separator
      5 
      6 X, y = make_blobs(centers=2, random_state=0)

ImportError: cannot import name 'plot_2d_separator' from 'figures' (C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\figures\__init__.py)
```

Comment: Can you give us a link to the `figures` project that provides the `plot_2d_separator` function? Also please include text-base output in code-blocks instead of images. That makes it easier to index and for us to do our research.

Comment: https://github.com/kcsazzal/scipy-2017-sklearn/blob/master/notebooks/05.Supervised_Learning-Classification.ipynb

Comment: For further information: I cloned the repository in my device and was working with creating my own notebook file and it was throwing an error, but if i execute the codes keeping in the file mentioned in the link above it doesn't show any error

Comment: This makes sense. The import is not provided by a python package, but a file that has a location relative to the notebook. Unfortunately, you cannot see this directly from the import statement. You will have to keep the file at the same relative location or add the location to your python path.

Comment: Thank you. I relocated my working file to the cloned repository where the other files are and it solved my problem.